# data values from database doesn't display full

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Patel Kalpanabase history-Valsad-Gujarat.pdf 
Link to PDF Patel Kalpanabase history-Valsad-Gujarat.pdf

Patel Hardikbase history-Valsad-Gujarat.pdf 
Link to PDF Patel Hardikbase history-Valsad-Gujarat.pdf

Ram Dayal-base history-Muzaffarpur-Bihar.pdf 
Link to PDF Ram Dayal-base history-Muzaffarpur-Bihar.pdf

Rathod Hetalbase history-Valsad-Gujarat.pdf 
Link to PDF Rathod Hetalbase history-Valsad-Gujarat.pdf

Geeta-base history-Meghnagar-Jhabua-Madhya Pradesh.p // should be pdf at the end rather displays p
Link to PDF Geeta-base history-Meghnagar-Jhabua-Madhya Pradesh.p

Jungle Singh-base history-Jhabua Batch-Madhya Prades// should be Pradesh.pdf at the end rather displays Prades
Link to PDF Jungle Singh-base history-Jhabua Batch-Madhya Prades
```

Can anyone tell why is the values been limited while displaying?

Comment: Is the data correct in the database? Or is it just when you retrieve it? Have you checked the column size (if it's a VARCHAR)? Is the data being truncated when it's stored?

Comment: its just when i retrieve it not able to display full

Comment: You need to add more detail here. How are you retrieving these values? Are you using stored procedures or inline query for retrieval? What is your schema or table structure? Please update your question.

Comment: @liquorvicar   u were correct i had used varchar(50)... can u update ur answer such that i can accept it!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you check the column size in your database schema. If you're using a VARCHAR column set to say 50 characters and the string is more than 50 chars then it will silently truncate the data when you insert it.

Comment: @dude No worries, thanks for the accept. I appreciate it. Perfect SO etiqutte IMHO!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have it stored in the database in a VARCHAR column with a too small length. Increase the column's length.